# Garbage in current iOS project with pod files

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods

I have created new project on iOS but I see to many dependencies with my another project where I used pods. 'ChatApp' is my new project and 'SlideOutMenu' is my old (you can see it on pic) It's so strange because I have no use pods in new project. But it exists in ChatApp.
I tried to

```
pod clean
pod install
pod update
```

but it not help and too many unnecessary files still in my project and I have many warnings. How can I kick unnessesary files from my new project and dispose warnings?

[See the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQZJt.png)

This is a picture which shows garbage from different project in my new proj

Comment: Search those files by name in the project. You may found those files with red color. Remove those files one by one. Use the bottom search option of project navigator in Xcode. Next remove  frameworks header file which you included in other viewcontroller by `#import` .

Comment: @Poles thx, but I tried to search on it, and I have no results by this ;( that files are missing in project.

Comment: Trash the contents of `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: @EricAya yes! it helped! I cleaned this directory and reload my project, now it's ok. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it. You just need to clean that folder. Thx for help! **[Eric Aya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2227743/eric-aya)**

> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/